# dividir cadenas en java

Tags: java

hola buenas les explico un problema algo facil pero nose como unir todo, pasa que me gustaria partir una cadena se que uno puede usar por ejemplo el comando split de java, pero pasa que yo ocupo dividir una cadena por varios identificadores algo como

```
split("[;=)(]")
```

pero pasa que ocupo combinar estos identificadores para partir la cadena con partirla por espacios vacíos que seria

```
split(" ")
```

pero ocupo combinar las dos formas y nose como podria hacerlo tengo algo como esto

```
lectura = lectura.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " ");

if (lectura.trim().length() > 0) {

String[] lexemas = lectura.split(" "); // aquí esta el problema o divido las cadenas por espacios o por "[;=)(]", pero nose como meter ambas. 
                             
System.out.println(lexemas[0]);
```

Comment: ¿Qué? Solo entendí que necesitas dividir la cadena. Danos un ejemplo de la entrada y el resultado esperado. También intenta explicar mejor la pregunta para que le sea útil a otras personas.

Answer (score 1):

Para dividir la cadena y crear un array, aquí debes usar `.split("\\s+")` :

```
//String[] lexemas = lectura.split(" ");
String[] lexemas = lectura.split("\\s+");
```

pero inicialmente no reemplaces los espacios:

```
//lectura = lectura.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " ");

if (lectura.trim().length() > 0) {

//String[] lexemas = lectura.split(" "); // aquí esta el problema o divido las cadenas por espacios o por "[;=)(]", pero nose como meter ambas. 
String[] lexemas = lectura.split("\\s+");
                             
System.out.println(lexemas[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes complejizar la expresión regular para que tome dos alternativas usando el carácter | de esta manera:

```
    String[] lexemas = "Este es;un(texto no tan=largo)de prueba".split("[;=)(]|\\s");
    for (String str : lexemas) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

El resultado es:

```
Este
es
un
texto
no
tan
largo
de
prueba
```